# Зависает после этапа выбора простой/расширенной установки

Tags: ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить **Ubuntu 20.04.01** второй операционкой к **Windows 10**. При установке намертво зависает после этапа выбора простой/расширенной установки.

Появилось ощущение, что дело в разрядности: запускал на **MobaLiveCD**, и тот сказал, что версия 64-битная, а процессор у меня 32-битный (хотя он 64-битный); 32-битная версия 14.04.6, кажется, нормально зашла на эмуляторе. Пробовал и **rufus**, и **Unetbootin**.

Автозагрузка в биос отключена. Образ скачивал и через интернет, и через торрент. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

**P.S.**
Ставлю на ноутбук **Asus**, процессор Intel `i3-6006U`, `64-битный`, `2000ГГц`, `6Гб ОЗУ`, `400Гб HDD` (из них `100` выделил под линукс).

**P.P.S.** Если выбрать запуск с флешки, а не установку, вылетает черный экран с ошибкой `PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer`

Comment: Установка в EFI или в Legacy режиме выполняется?

Comment: Перед запуском измени параметры запуска убери quite тогда, вероятно, сможешь прочитать, на чем ядро ушло в панику? если тебе десктопное окружение не основной критерий и хватит командной строки, тогда можешь поставить WSL(через панель управления, установку доп комп. виндны) и установи убутну в него с магазина MS.

Comment: Поставьте сначала на виртуалке; отключите fast boot в винде; с руфусом у меня всё было нормально

Comment: Ставлю в EFI (я так понял), а виртуалка не дает поставить 20ю версию и говорит, что у меня 32-битный процессор, хотя он 64-битный. Винда вообще обещала долго жить и слетела.